# PHP sort downgrade version from 7 to 5 result issue

Tags: php, wordpress, php-7

I have this line of code here, which is working on PHP v7 but on php5 i'm getting an mysql syntax error.

```
 $row_sub = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *  from $sub_service WHERE subid IN($str_sub_serviced) ORDER BY subname ASC");
```

Error log

```
 WordPress database error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY subname' at line 1 for query SELECT *  from mtd_subservices WHERE subid IN() ORDER BY subname made by require
```

What would it be a proper fix for php5?

i've tried arsort($row_sub) but no success.

Thank you

Comment: How is $str_sub_serviced sourced/defined because it looks empty in your error log.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL returns this exact syntax error when you call "IN()" without or with empty parameter so make sure `$str_sub_serviced` is a string and not empty.